# Get respective part from string

Tags: php, string, split

Kindly let me know how to get the part `Application6.docx` from strings like  `files/abcd/Application6.docx` ?

In simple words I am just trying to get the file name along with its extension `Application6.docx`

Note: `files/abcd/` can be different `ppt/file/` so I cannot use the trick of replacing `files/abcd/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use basename to get what you want.

```
$file = basename("files/abcd/Application6.docx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope This Helps :)

```
<?php
     $url = "http://test.com/beta/files_images/file.php";
     $keys = parse_url($url); // Parse the url
     $data = explode("/", $keys['path']); 
     $last = end($data); 
 ?>
```